# Not able to see the sidemenu icon in Ionic 3 even after the menu is enabled using MenuController

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I would like to display `sidemenu` icon on my `Home` page. The user navigates to this `Home` page from the `Add-Contract` page.

The problem is that I have enabled `sidemenu` in `home.ts` using 
`this.menu.enable(true);` but still the `sidemenu` icon is not visible. 
However, I can still swipe and see the menu.

Please guide.

**home.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private menu: MenuController) {
    this.menu.enable(true);
  }

  accountSettings() {
    this.navCtrl.push(AccountSettingsPage);
  }

  logout() {
    this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
  }

}
```

**home.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar hideBackButton="true">
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button (click)="accountSettings()" icon-only ion-button>
        <ion-icon name="settings"></ion-icon>
      </button>
      <button (click)="logout()" icon-only ion-button>
        <ion-icon name="log-out"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
 //some more code here
</ion-content-padding>
```

**add-contract.ts (this page takes the user to Home page)**

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-add-contract',
  templateUrl: 'add-contract.html',
})
export class AddContractPage {

   constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private navCtrl: NavController, private menu: MenuController) {
    this.menu.enable(false);
   }

   ionViewDidEnter() {
      this.menu.swipeEnable(false);
   }

   ionViewDidLeave() {
     this.menu.swipeEnable(true);
     this.menu.enable(true);
   }

   //takes the user to Home page
   addContract(val: any) {
      this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
   }
}
```

Comment: nothing wrong with your code. can you reproduce this in https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: I went there but could not generate a new page as there was no terminal. I wanted to place a button one of the tab page and navigate to next page on click of it.

Comment: I recently tried adding `     <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>' in about.html but could not see the sidemenu icon

Comment: share the stackblitz link

Comment: https://ionic-kaqn5h.stackblitz.io

Comment: I cannot edit your code using above link, at least i cannot see your code

Comment: your link should be like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-6uqd8e

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-kaqn5h

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `ion-menu` to **app.html** as below. Then you can see the menu toggle icon.

```
<ion-menu type="overlay" [content]="content">
</ion-menu>
```

See my [stackblitz solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-6c3twq?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)

Comment: When I click on this link I don't see the change made by you or the sidemenu icon for that sake.

Comment: Where do I add this in home.html?

Comment: Oh, ok, I see it should be app.html

Comment: Added it in app.html and now my app.html looks like `<ion-menu type="overlay" [content]="content">
  <ion-header>` but still don't see the sidemenu

Comment: See my stackblitz example that provided with my answer and compare it with your code.

Comment: I copy-pasted your code over mine and also removed the hideBackButton="true" flag. I see that the Back button is appearing but not the sidemenu icon. Looks like something is overwriting it.

Comment: I gave you the solution. Arranging the solution according to your requirement is up to you.